# Call a PHP instance method with another PHP file in system memory

Tags: php, sockets, soap, pipeline

I have a PHP socket server script named `server.php` that binding to a certain port and keep running for a long time. (actually it start in cli (terminal) mode and not will stop until ctrl+c command pressed.)
Also there is a Soap-server PHP file named `service.php` that manage chat requests. (for example open a new room, accept or kick clients and so on.)
Both two scripts access to a common database, so they can shared information.

But sometime it's necessary for SoapServer to call some methods of SocketServer (that it's running in system memory) asynchronously and get related data.

I'm looking for a simple and certain way to handle that. thanx for any tips.

Comment: You would need to provide some more information.. Just the name of a script and the fact that it's listening on a certain port doesn't provide many clues. It would seem obvious that SoapServer could use curl to connect to the port SocketServer is listening on.

Comment: This socket server is working for WebSocket (Javascript Clients). if i'm going to connect it, SoapServer must act as a WebSocket too. (And also considering some security conditions like pin code.) But is it possible to connect to a port as a WebSocket in PHP?

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it? It's network communication, and PHP can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the little information I think your best bet is to ensure server.php does only one thing: opening a socket (e.g. on port 8001) and serve. It shouldn't contain any methods at all.

You put your methods in another script, let's call it handler.php. In server.php you include it: `require_once("handler.php");`

Nothing stops you from opening another socket on another port (e.g. 8002) that does not handle persistent connections, but instead responds to regular web requests. Call it server2.php for example. This server2.php also contains: `require_once("handler.php");`

Then the SoapServer can use curl to make async requests to port 8002 and have access to the same methods that server.php uses for the persistent connection(s).

A websocket that listens to regular ajax / web requests could look something like the code below. In my case handler.php has a method `handle()` that handles the `$rawInput` based on the `$query`. The `$query` could be as simple as the name of the method you want to invoke.

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ob_start();
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
set_time_limit(0);
require_once("handler.php");
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, "127.0.0.1" , 8002);
socket_listen($sock, 1024);  

while (true) {  
    $client   = socket_accept($sock); 
    $rawInput = socket_read($client, 204800);
    $input    = explode("\r\n", $rawInput); 
    $input    = explode(" ", $input[0]);
    $query    = isset($input[1]) ? $input[1] : '/';     
    $result   = handle($query, $rawInput);
    $headers  = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
    $headers .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Length: " . sprintf('%u', strlen($result)) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r\n";
    $output   = $headers . "\r\n" . $result;

    socket_write($client, $output, strlen($output));
    socket_shutdown($client, 1);
    socket_close($client);
}

socket_shutdown($sock);
socket_close($sock);
```

This example is taken from some code that I wrote and I'm actively using, removing the lines of code that are specific to my application. I hope it works for you too..

Because the information provided was minimal - I don't know why you can't just let Apache have access to handler.php as well. But if it needs to be a websocket, above example could do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed descriptions. Your tips was too helpful for me but I have to command server.php directly in order to control clients. Accessing to clients management from web-socket will be to risky (even if pin code needed) but I think making a certain header (with pin code of course) is not a bad idea, is it?

Comment: Headers do not provide additional security. ?pincode=1234 in a query string is just as insecure as header("pincode: 1234")

Comment: Not so simple! :D, Request store in database by Soap-server. (so it's not visible for everyone.) Then request ID and a rand pin code that stored in database, send to server.php by a custom header. then server.php process this request if it's valid. It's good for logging too.